# Header banner won't resize on mobile phone/small tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design

Because of the height/design of this company's logo we created an header image that includes it. That header image is located here:

http://tinyurl.com/oqkpvff

Anyone know how to make that header image resize automatically for mobile/smaller tablet?

```
#title-container {
background-image: url("url of our image is here") !important;
background-position: left top !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
height: 250px;
max-width: 100% !important;
position: relative;
}
```

I did try height: auto but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [background-size: contain;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/pm83k/)**

```
#title-container {
    background-image: url("http://tinyurl.com/oqkpvff");
    background-position: left top !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

> **contain**
>
> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible >while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

Comment: Juan - thank you. The banner background image now resizes correctly but the header-container does not so it creates big gap 

`code`
#wrapper.boxed #header-container {
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
`code`